# Finding a general indefinite integral involving trig

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have to solve the following,

$$\int \frac{8\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)}dx$$

but I'm not sure where to begin. I thought of the anti derivative been something like -4cos(2x) but that doesn't take care of the sin in the denominator. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Do you know an identity involving $\sin2x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use the following trigonometric identity:
$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$